# bootstrap typography

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typography

By default Bootstrap has `@baseFontSize: 14px` and `@baseLineHeight: 20px`. I'm planning to use 12px as my `@baseFontSize`. Should I reduce @baseLineHeight to 17px for correct typography and inputs rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typography has no fixed rules for line height. The line height should be selected with due attention to things like font family, line length, presence or absence of diacritic marks,  subscripts, and superscripts, etc.

Twitter Bootstrap uses by default Helvetica Neue or Helvetica in the relatively few situations they are available, otherwise Arial. For such fonts, a relatively large line height like 20px for 4px font (about 1.429 times the font size) is mostly OK. In a narrow column, it might be a little excessive. Using 17px for 12px means practically the same proportion (about 1.417 times the font size).

Of course, no amount of line height tuning can fix the problem that 12px font size is illegible to many people.